# Developing OSX applications with JavaScript/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, cordova, desktop

I know there is Phonegap and Nimblekit to develop native applications for mobile platforms with JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3. I'm looking for the desktop equivalent of this.

I have found Appjs, Adobe Air, Cappuccino and Titanium but all of those don't seem to accomplish what I'm looking for. Basically, I want to create an .app with webtechnologies.

Could any of you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at app.js: http://appjs.org/

Comment: Thx but appjs just doesn't cut it for me... Unless of course there is a way to make it into an .app?

Comment: When you say ".app" are you referring to a desktop Mac application?  If so, you should be able to package it up using something like this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Workflow/Workflow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005371-CH1000-SW1

Comment: Yeah, i am referring to a desktop application for the osx platform.

Comment: Titanium by Appcelerator also provides Crossplatform for Destkop Applications. EDIT: I just found an article that said they dont support the project anymore.

Comment: Like i said, Titanium doesn't work for me. The desktop sdk split of into a separate project called TideSDK. Still, it won't work for me since it has no lion support.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Mac port of PhoneGap.

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-mac.git;a=summary

Comment: https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-mac
These are the same devs right?

Comment: Yes, that is the github mirror of the project.

Answer (score 0):

[MacGap](https://github.com/maccman/macgap) is what you are looking for.

**Update 01.22.2014:** [node-webkit-hipster-seed](https://github.com/Anonyfox/node-webkit-hipster-seed), despite its less-than-informative name, combines a lot of different front end tools together for a Desktop application authoring workflow. It's based on [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit).

Comment: I already looked into that, not exactly what i want..

Comment: @Rutgerinc MacGap packages as a `.app`, and is about as native as it gets. I'd recommend MacGap, as it is (I'd say) is the best option for OS X. Other than that, you named the rest in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try Apache Cordova mac. OSX support is not officially released yet but you can give it a shot

https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx

You can also look at electron

http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*